# Only one value to submitting on form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with these fields and for some reason attendance only comes through as 'Yes' despite you selecting the 'No' radio button.

Any ideas why and if there is anything wrong with what I have done?

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="No" id="attendance" />
    Yes</label> 
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="Yes" id="attendance" />
    No</label>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 elements with the same ID?

Comment: There has to be more to your code than this if this is happening. This should work as you expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="Yes" id="attendance-yes" />
    Yes</label> 
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="No" id="attendance-no" />
    No</label>
```

you had your labels and your values reversed...

Answer (score 2):

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="No" id="attendance" />
    No</label> 
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="Yes" id="attendance" />
    Yes</label>
```

Your label is `No` while the value of the radio button is `Yes` :)

Also as others have noted: you cannot have two elements with the same `id`. You could just use a `class` for this.

Comment: Was just answering the same thing, but you haven't actually fixed his code ;)

Comment: @Jospeh Silber: But I was first! :P And you made a typo... :D

Comment: Let's break up the fight little kids, PeeHaa gets this one :P

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same `id` for two elements. Remove `id` or assign different `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` should be unique, so you should give the elements different identities.

I'm not sure if that is the cause of the problem, but that is the only error in the code that you have shown. If that doesn't help, the problem is in the part of the code that you haven't shown.

---

As others have mentioned, you have swapped the values and labels betwwen the radio buttons, but that seems to be too obvious...

Comment: `but that seems to be too obvious`. It can never be too obvious! :-)

Answer (score -1):

I see two mistakes in the code given:

- the label tag should only surround the effective label (not the input tag)
- the two items have the same id, i think that's why you always get the same result

Comment: -1 A `label` may surround an `input`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9

Comment: I prefer wrapping my inputs in labels (mostly), saves me from writing the `for` attribute on the label. P.S having same ID's doesn't matter to the server because just the name and value is sent back.

Answer (score -1):

You might differenciate the ID as it should be unique. Also you could use the attribute `for` for the label markup.

Like this :

```
<label for="attendanceyes">
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="Yes" id="attendanceyes" />
    Yes
</label>

<label for="attendanceno">
    <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="No" id="attendanceno" />
    No
</label>
```

Comment: -1 When the `label`s surround the `input`s, they don't need the `for` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9